# htaccess - redirect only non-subdomain requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess

...except www, which is a subdomain too, of course.

This is my current htaccess rule with added comments:

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#what does this do?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/

#rewrite /a/1 to /index.php?action=a&urlId=1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&urlId=$2 [L,QSA]

#rewrite /a to /index.php?action=a
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now my problem is, I added two subdomains a.domain.com and b.domain.com that point to the same directory and therefor go through the same htaccess - but they are used for direct static file-access. How can I prevent `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` to use the above rules completely?

And maybe someone could explain what this does:

```
#what does this do?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to add a condition that check if the host is domain.com before executing the RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
```

regarding your second question, one or more RewriteCond directives are not seperate instructions but associated with a RewriteRule, they are conditions that must be valid to execute the RewriteRule.

in your case :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&urlId=$2 [L,QSA]
```

the rewriteRule is executed only if the requested uri does not point to a file, and does not begin with /login/.

Comment: thank you Amine! I added your first line just under RewriteEngine On and it seems to work! For the 2nd question: What does !-f mean? I know, "understand your code" would also be a valid answer ;)